# Why a tensor product of $2\times 2$ unitaries cannot implement a $3\times 3$ unitary?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, quantum-computation

Let $\{v_1, \dotsc, v_m\} \in \mathbb{C}^{2^n}$ be a set of orthonormal vectors. Define a map $R_m$ from $2^n \times 2^n$ to $m \times m$ matrices as follows:
$$R_m(M) := \sum_{i,j=1}^m (v_i^*M v_j) E_{ij}$$
where $E_{ij} := e_i e_j^*$ is the all-zeroes matrix with entry 1 at position $(i,j)$. In other words, $R_m$ performs a unitary change of basis and then takes the top-left $3 \times 3$ block of the resulting matrix.

For any $n \geq 2$, show that no matter how the vectors $\{v_i\}$ are chosen,
$$\mathrm{U}(3) \not\subseteq \bigl\{ R_3(U_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes U_n) : U_i \in \mathrm{U}(2) \bigr\}.$$
That is, as matrices $U_i$ range over all possible $2 \times 2$ unitaries, their tensor product will never contain the set of all $3 \times 3$ unitaries in some basis.

More generally, this should hold even if $2 \times 2$ unitaries are replaced by $d \times d$ unitaries and $m = 3$ is replaced by any $m > d$. The motivation for this question comes from "encoded universality" in quantum computing.

Comment: $R_3(U)$ simply isn't unitary unless $L(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ happens to be an invariant subspace of $U$.

Comment: Yes, that's also my intuition. But can you prove that it will never be an invariant subspace?

Comment: @MarisOzols: All I'm saying is for any choice of $v_1,v_2,v_3$, there is a $U$ that doesn't fix this subspace. This is enough to establish the inequality (the set on the LHS contains non-unitary matrices).

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Now that my question has been answered, I finally realized what I was actually after. Indeed, the fact the resulting matrix might not be unitary is a trivial reason why the set of matrices I'm interested will have nothing to do with $\mathrm{U}(3)$ in general. However, it could still happen that one gets all of $\mathrm{U}(3)$ plus some non-unitary matrices. Instead of equality, what I actually would like to prove is the relation $\not\supseteq$.

Comment: I just updated the question accordingly. The updated question has now also been answered by user1551.

Comment: **Erratum.** In the last sentence of the above bounty information, $V^\ast(U_1\otimes\cdots\otimes U_m)V$ should read $V^\ast(U_1\otimes\cdots\otimes U_{\color{red}{n}})V$

Comment: In order to decide what the upper $3\times3$ block of a Kronecker product of matrices is you need to specify an orderiing of the basis elements. Not sure whether the answer depends on that choice though.

Comment: I think that the difficulties of getting this answered may be related to something other than this being at research level (I don't think it is, but I may be wrong). I see that you are interested in quantum computing. You could ask this at [TheoreticalComputerScience.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). IIRC Pete Shor frequents that site.

Comment: I just posted this question to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198166/why-a-tensor-product-of-2-times-2-unitaries-cannot-implement-a-3-times-3-uni